# What's the proof of this lemma?

Tags: probability, general-topology, random-variables, convex-analysis

[Lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOOPB.png)

Hello, I've been working on this article : "The Asymptotic Elasticity of utility functions and Optimal Investment in Incomplete Market" that uses this lemma on multiple occasions without giving a proof for it.

Maybe it's obvious but I don't really now how to prove it, any suggestions ?